# Opengl VAO and VBO objects

Tags: c++, opengl, constructor

I want to create multiple vertex buffers in objects (one by object). the constructor is:

```
VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer(const GLvoid *data,
                           GLsizeiptr size,
                           GLenum mode, 
                           GLsizei count, 
                           GLsizei stride,
                           ShaderInterface *shaderInterface,
                           GLvoid *positionOffset,
                           GLvoid *normalOffset)
    : _mode(mode),
    _count(count),
    _stride(stride),
    _shaderInterface(shaderInterface),
    _positionOffset(positionOffset),
    _normalOffset(normalOffset)

{
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //
    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //??????
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    //
}
```

If I create 1 object VertexBuffer, this works ok. But if I create another object (I won't use it) and I draw the first object again the result is not correct (for example, the object showed is in other place). Why?

Comment: You should show your drawing code too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to store the `vao` anywhere, but you should. Before drawing each object you shall `glBindVertexArray` its `vao` (but not `_vertexBufferID`) before you call any of `glDraw*`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537552/277176) to see what state VAOs contain.