# Do I need to call glEnableVertexAttribArray if I use VAOs?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, vbo, vao

I understood that VAOs can store bindings to VBOs and index VBOs (both `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), but now I have a question:

```
void render()
{
    ..Set up textures, uniforms..

    glBindVertexArray(vaoId)); // This also binds VBOs and indices VBOs 
    automatically (if it was properly set up)

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Do I need this?
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Do I need this?
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // Do I need this?

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices_N, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    .. cleanup..
}
```

Do I still need to call `glEnableVertexAttribArray` even if I already bound a VAO properly set up?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41537552/277176), it should sort the things out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessary. You should have already called `glEnableVertexAttribArray` during the VAO setup so they get enabled automatically when the VAO gets bound.